# physics body does't coincide with SKNodes frame

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

In my program I have sea and drops, falling into the sea. And drops disappears when they contact the sea. Sea is the SpriteNode at the bottom of the scene, and it's physics body must coincide with it's frame. That is the description of sea:

```
sea = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(self.size.width, 100)];
sea.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMinY(self.frame));
//sea.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),400);

[self addChild:sea];
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(sea.frame), CGRectGetMidY(sea.frame));
sea.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:sea.frame.size center:center];
sea.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
sea.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategorySea;
sea.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
sea.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CollisionCategoryDrop;
sea.zPosition = 2;
```

Problem is that contact between drop and sea become only after some time since drop disappear under the scene, like as the physics appears somewhere under the scene (but visible frame is placed at the bottom of scene). And if uncomment the third line

```
 sea.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),400);
```

then visible frame would be near the middle of scene and collisions would be at the bottom.
Furthermore, space between visible body and physics body decreases when I increase y-coordinate of sea, and they coincide when y is near 700.

Comment: enable physics debug drawing

Comment: All right, error was with drops, not with sea. I set wrong drops physics bodes position.